Which linear transformations on hermitian 2x2 matrices fix the determinant?
We consider the four dimensional real vector space $H$ of all $2\times 2$ hermitian matrices. The determinant is a function $\det\colon H\to\mathbb{R}$. I am interested in the subgroup $G$ of $\textrm{GL}(H)$ of all $\mathbb{R}$-linear automorphisms $\psi$ of $H$ such that $\det\circ\psi=\det$.
It is clear that taking the transpose is an element of $G$. Also every element $S$ of $\textrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ induces an element of $G$ via $A\mapsto SAS^*$. Are these all in the sense that these elements generate $G$?
I would be happy about an argument but even more about a reference.

under the action $A\mapsto SAS^{-1}$, every element $S\in\text{GL}(H)$ fixes the determinant, since $\det(S^{-1}) = \det(S)^{-1}$

I think this action is not well-defined. $H$ is a $4$-dimensional real vector space, so $S$ is a $4\times 4$ matrix. $A$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix.

The space of $2\times 2$ hermitian matrices has dimension $4$ (real dimension!). Such a matrix has real diagonal entries, and the off diagonals are a complex conjugate pair. So, such a matrix is in the form
\begin{pmatrix}
x & y+iz\\
y-iz & w
\end{pmatrix}
Its determinant is $\det=xw-y^2-z^2$. Therefore, the group you are after is the subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_4(\mathbb{R})$ which preserves this symmetric, bilinear form.
You can diagonalise this symmetric, bilinear form by a change of variables: $u=\frac{x+w}{2}$ and $v=\frac{x-w}{2}$ gives $\det=u^2-v^2-y^2-z^2$. The group you are after therefore is the Lorentz group $\operatorname{O}(1,3)$ of linear transformations of $\mathbb{R}^4$ preserving this indefinite, symmetric bilinear form.

Thank you! Why $\textrm{SO}(1,3)$ and not $\textrm{O}(1,3)$? Also this does not quite answer my question, which is, phrased in your language: Does the image of $\textrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ and the transposition generate the Lorentz group?

Okay, using the wikipedia article I could figure out that there is one more involution necessary to generate the full Lorentz group.

You're right, it is $\operatorname{O}(1,3)$, I've fixed that.
